# Define a decimal max value with the mask RegEx regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, mask

I need to define a maximum value for a field. I'm using the mask reg ex, ([1-9]?[0-9])|(100), and it's working normally for value between 1 to 100, but I need the value to be from 0,1 to 100.
(I'm sorry for my mistakes in english).

Comment: Just parse your field value to double and check it's value is between 0.1 and 100?

Comment: But I need to do using a mask. Thank you

Comment: Why do you need to do it with RegEx? Homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex works for any decimal number between 0.1 and 100:

```
^(100|([1-9]\d|[1-9])(\.\d+)?|0\.[1-9]\d*)$
```

explanation: 100 or ((number between 10 and 99) or (number between 1 and 9) possibly with decimal digits) or (decimal number between 0.1 and 0.9 with decimal digits)

tested with below code in C# console

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^(100|([1-9]\d|[1-9])(\.\d+)?|0\.[1-9]\d*)$");
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r.IsMatch(Console.ReadLine()));
}
```

Comment: "**from 0,1** to 100", Your regex checks for 1 only.

Comment: Thanks, but It's not working. The value must be from 0.1 to 100. I had in the code, but I have to make using RegEx.

Comment: The regex is not working for value 10,x, for example.

Comment: I meant 10 in decimal value (x means "any number")

Comment: Will now work between 0.1 and 100 (I royally messed up this answer sorry)

Comment: Yes, between 0.1 and 100. I'm Brazilian, and here 0.1 means 0,1.

Comment: 10.5 works for me, maybe try '[0-9]' instead of '\d'

Comment: Are you using a string literal or just a plain string to do it? because there may be a problem there.  if plain string put a '@' before it as in '@"regex"'

Comment: I'm not doing in the source code, I'm doing in the interface

Comment: Made it so it will match it exactly, but still do not see your problem that 10.5 doesn't work as it works in C# source code

Comment: I will try other options. Thank you, guy, and happy new year.

Comment: It's working \o/ Actually, it was not working because I had defined a maxlength for the field. I'm sorry and thank you so much.